# Laravel wrong limit inside function with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There are three models `User` `Post` and `Image`.
The user has many posts, posts have many images. Also, there is a `user_images` function - it's
`hasManyThrough` function. All relations work well.
During the search, I wanna get users with images(max 3 for every user) and do something like that:

```
$users = User::where('is_active', true)
            ->with([
                'user_images' => function ($relation) {
                    $relation->limit(self::LIMIT_IMAGES);
                }
            ])->get();
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 265,
    "user_images": [
      {
        "id": 309,
        "path": "url"
      },
      {
        "id": 308,
        "path": "url"
      },
      {
        "id": 306,
        "path": "url"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 305,
    "user_images": []
  }
]
```

As you can I have **ONLY** 3 images for all users, not for every. But if I use Lazy Eager Loading(function load) with the same limit, all works well.
Can someone explain that behavior?

Comment: There is no native support for this in Laravel. You need to create custom method or use third party package as @OMR mentioned below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit) package

after installing it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

you just have to use it inside the model you want to use limited eager loading:

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

// ....
}


class UserImage extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

// ....
}
```

now your limited eager loading will be fetched correctly.

Comment: thx for the advice, but it seems not good for me to use the package just for limit selection. Also wanna find out something about `with`. Is it native behavior or it is a bug?